# search functionality for nested array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, filter

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App =() => {
const groups = [
      {
       name: "Male 9 A",
       options: [
         { label: "Team 1", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 2", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 3", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 4", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 5", selected: false }
       ]
      },
    {
       name: "Male 9 B",
         options: [
         { label: "Team 1B", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 2B", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 3B", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 4B", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 5B", selected: false },
       ]
      }
     ];
const [searchFilter, setSearchfilter] = useState(groups);

  let search = searchFilter.filter((group) => {
      return group.options.find((player) => 
       player.label.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()))
     })
      .map((data) => ({
      ...data,
      options: data.options.filter(player =>  
       player.label.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()))
       }));
      console.log(search);
      setSearchfilter(search);
      }
        return (
        <> 
        <input type="text" onChange={(e) => searchList(e)} placeholder="Search"/>
           </> 
        )
        };
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

I am writing a search function for this nested array but it is not working the way i want it work so the thing is if i am searching for Team 1B then i should get [{name: "Male 9 B", options: [{ label: "Team 1B", selected: false }] and i am also getting result but when i clear the input field i am not able to find other group name. i have mentioned the array and function which i have written.

It is a search functionality

```
<input type="text" className="head-1" onChange={(e) => searchList(e)} placeholder="Search"/>



const groups = [
      {
       name: "Male 9 A",
       options: [
         { label: "Team 1", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 2", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 3", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 4", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 5", selected: false }
       ]
      },
    {
       name: "Male 9 B",
         options: [
         { label: "Team 1B", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 2B", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 3B", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 4B", selected: false },
         { label: "Team 5B", selected: false },
       ]
      }
     ];



  let search = groups.filter((group) => {
      return group.options.find((player) => 
       player.label.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()))
     })
      .map((data) => ({
      ...data,
      options: data.options.filter(player =>  
       player.label.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()))
       }));
      console.log(search);
      }
```

Comment: pls provide a working snippet in the question with `searchList` function

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev i tried but not able to understand how to add code snippet for react

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo You have used `group` instead of `groups` in the filter function. The event object needs to be passed to the search function. Make sure you pass the event object to the function like `searchFunction(event)` Find the updated code below.

```
const groups = [
  {
    name: "Male 9 A",
    options: [
      { label: "Team 1", selected: false },
      { label: "Team 2", selected: false },
      { label: "Team 3", selected: false },
      { label: "Team 4", selected: false },
      { label: "Team 5", selected: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Male 9 B",
    options: [
      { label: "Team 1B", selected: false },
      { label: "Team 2B", selected: false },
      { label: "Team 3B", selected: false },
      { label: "Team 4B", selected: false },
      { label: "Team 5B", selected: false }
    ]
  }
];

function searchFunction(event) {
  let search = groups
    .filter((group) => {
      return group.options.find((player) =>
        player.label.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
      );
    })
    .map((data) => ({
      name: data.name,
      options: data.options.filter((player) =>
        player.label.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
      )
    }));

   console.log(JSON.stringify(search, null, 2));
}

// Call the function with an example event
const exampleEvent = { target: { value: "Team 1B" } };
searchFunction(exampleEvent);
```

The output will look like below

```
[
  {
    "name": "Male 9 B",
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "Team 1B",
        "selected": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: sorry for the typo but this functionality is working fine but not with search functionality that is the issue. It is one time working for search functionality.